Get a message during a submitted job
Hello everyone (first thing sorry for my english, it's not my native language),
I have a basic clle program, the purpose is to count the file total size in a library. At the end the programm should send a message with the total size, here is a part of the code

start:                                                                          
         RTVJOBA    USER(&USER)                                              
         DSPOBJD    OBJ(&LIB/*ALL) OBJTYPE(*FILE) +                          
                      OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(QTEMP/QADSPOBJ)               
                                                                             
         OVRDBF     FILE(QADSPOBJ) TOFILE(QTEMP/QADSPOBJ)                    
         DOWHILE    COND(&LEC)                                               
         rcvf                                                                
         MONMSG     MSGID(CPF0864) EXEC(LEAVE)                               
         chgvar  var(&TOTSIZE) value(&TOTSIZE + &ODOBSZ)                     
         enddo                                                               
                                                                             
       /* SNDPGMMSG msg('Total size of files in library ' -                  
                     !! &lib !< ' is ' !! %char(&TOTSIZE) !! ' bytes.') */   
         SNDMSG     MSG('Total size of files in library ' !! +               
                      &LIB !< ' is ' !! %CHAR(&TOTSIZE) !> ' +               
                      bytes.') TOUSR(&USER)                                  
         return   


When I call the prog everything is ok, I get the message, but if I submit the program using a sbmjob, the job ends normally but no message. I have 2 question:

where does the msg go?
is there a better way to send the message back to the message queue of the user who submitted the batch job?

Merci

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Also removing the [clp] tag as that is not for IBM i control language.

You would expect SNDMSG to work, particularly if you are sending it to your own user ID from a batch job being run under your user id.
You would need to use the DSPMSG command to show your messages.
If the batch job isn't running under your user profile, then check to see if the profile it's running under has sufficient authority.

Restrictions:

You must have object operational (*OBJOPR) and add (*ADD) authorities    for the message queue.
You must have use (*USE) authority for the    specified message queues and *USE authority for the libraries in    which they are
located.


You may also want to consider using Send User Message (SNDUSRMSG) as suggested in the docs, "Completion and diagnostic messages"

Thank you Charles i ll look into that, i m training on pub400 so maybe there is this restriction.
I'll give the result of your suggestion.

thank you, both codes work as soon as TOUSR and MSGTYPE have a value :
code SNDPGMMSG  MSG('Total size of files in library ' !! +
&LIB !< ' is ' !! %CHAR(&TOTSIZE) !< ' bytes.') TOUSR(&USER) MSGTYPE(*INFO)
SNDMSG     MSG('Total size of files in library ' !! +
&LIB !< ' is ' !! %CHAR(&TOTSIZE) !< ' bytes.') TOUSR(&USER) MSGTYPE(*INFO)
SNDUSRMSG  MSG('Total size of files in library ' !! +
&LIB !< ' is ' !! %CHAR(&TOTSIZE) !< ' bytes.') TOUSR(&USER) MSGTYPE(*INFO)
code
